# SQL Server Compact Edition connection string

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, sql-server-ce, connection-string

I am installing SQL Server Compact edition on the user computer. So what is the connection string to SSCE ?

Comment: Which error? Describe it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection Format is:

```
Data Source=MyData.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;
```

Comment: Didn't work for me with SSCE 4 until I added reference to System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll version 4.0 (in Extentions list) and replaced SqlConnection by **SqlCeConnection**

Answer (score 1):

Check [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005-ce).

```
Data Source=MyData.sdf;Encrypt Database=True;Password=myPassword;File Mode=shared read;Persist Security Info=False;
```

Answer (score -3):

Check [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008)

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

You have to pay attention to Source. If you already have another instance of SQL server installed than you have to change the Source (example: `Source=MyPCName/SQL-INSTANCE-NAME`)

Comment: He needs a connection string for a SQL Server **Compact Edition** - that's **NOT** a "real" server, but just a `.sdf` file.... this connection string that you show works for a "regular" SQL Server - but **NOT** for Compact Edition....

Comment: The OP asked for a `SQL Server Compact Edition` connection string, not a regular SQL Server one.